# Realm latency between writes in the background thread and retrieving objects in the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, background, realm

In my app, I am synchronizing all my data via realm transactions in the background thread. However, occasionally when I try to retrieve a recently synchronized object in the UI thread, I get a null pointer exception. I have written a routine that seems to be a fix to this small latency problem, but it feels like a "hacky" solution. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I have posted a simplified version of the routine below.

```
private void attemptToEnterActivity(){

    // Retrieve the object's key.
    String key = Application.getInstance().getRecentlySyncedPrimaryKey();

    // Retrieve the realm object with the key.
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    Object object = realm.where(Object.class)
            .equalTo("key", key)
            .findFirst();

    if (object != null) {
        new NavigationController(this).activity_start(new Intent(this, Activity.class));
    } else {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                attemptToEnterActivity();
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of guessing when the object will be fetched and stored, the suggestion is to use `RealmChangeListener`. See doc [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications) for more information.

In your case, you can also use Realm's async query like:

```
RealmResults<Object> results = realm.where(Object.class)
        .equalTo("key", key).findAllAsync();
results.addChnageListener(newRealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Object> objects) {
            if (objects.size() > 0) {
                Object object = objects.first();
                // ....
            }
        }
    });
```